# The effect of attribute data-auto-a11y in Font Awesome 5

Tags: javascript, attributes, font-awesome-5

If we want to use **SVG+JS** of rendering **[Font Awesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/configuration#configuration)** icon, then switch the
`css/all.css` into `js/all.js`.

Using a `<script>` tag in the browser:

```html
<script 
  src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/js/all.js" 
  data-auto-a11y="true">
</script>
```

My question is what is the effect of `data-auto-a11y` in Font Awesome 5?

Is it necessary to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diving into the Font Awesome code on GitHub, in particular at [/js/fontawesome.js](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/0d1f27efb836eb2ab994ba37221849ed64a73e5c/js/fontawesome.js)  first of all the `data-auto-a11y` attribute is mapped to a property `autoA11y`.  Searching for that through the code it looks like this property governs if various `aria-` attributes are set, specifically if `autoA11y` is `true` and there is a title attribute then [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) is set, otherwise [`aria-hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute) is set.

So, if you care about accessibility (and I think everybody should) then it does matter.  However, I would also add that, on other lines of the code, it seems to indicate that this being set to true is the default.  I would suggest you probably don't need it, however it would certainly in that case be harmless.

> Caveat: I know nothing *a priori* about the internal workings of Font
>   Awesome, this is just based on an analysis of the code.

### Font Awesome code snippets

Default settings ([line 257](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/0d1f27efb836eb2ab994ba37221849ed64a73e5c/js/fontawesome.js#L257))

```js
  var _default = {
    familyPrefix: DEFAULT_FAMILY_PREFIX,
    replacementClass: DEFAULT_REPLACEMENT_CLASS,
    autoReplaceSvg: true,
    autoAddCss: true,
    autoA11y: true,
    searchPseudoElements: false,
    observeMutations: true,
    mutateApproach: 'async',
    keepOriginalSource: true,
    measurePerformance: false,
    showMissingIcons: true
  };
```

Uses of `autoA11y`. ([Line 1605](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/0d1f27efb836eb2ab994ba37221849ed64a73e5c/js/fontawesome.js#L1605))

```js
  function attributesParser (node) {
    var extraAttributes = toArray(node.attributes).reduce(function (acc, attr) {
      if (acc.name !== 'class' && acc.name !== 'style') {
        acc[attr.name] = attr.value;
      }

      return acc;
    }, {});
    var title = node.getAttribute('title');

    if (config.autoA11y) {
      if (title) {
        extraAttributes['aria-labelledby'] = "".concat(config.replacementClass, "-title-").concat(nextUniqueId());
      } else {
        extraAttributes['aria-hidden'] = 'true';
        extraAttributes['focusable'] = 'false';
      }
    }

    return extraAttributes;
  }
```

and [line 1874](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/0d1f27efb836eb2ab994ba37221849ed64a73e5c/js/fontawesome.js#L1874)

```js
    if (config.autoA11y && !title) {
      extra.attributes['aria-hidden'] = 'true';
    }
```

and finally [line 2291](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/0d1f27efb836eb2ab994ba37221849ed64a73e5c/js/fontawesome.js#L2291)

```js
      if (config.autoA11y) {
        if (title) {
          attributes['aria-labelledby'] = "".concat(config.replacementClass, "-title-").concat(nextUniqueId());
        } else {
          attributes['aria-hidden'] = 'true';
          attributes['focusable'] = 'false';
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help and concise response to my question.